# Cannot access WCF service from IE

Tags: wcf, rest

This has probably been discussed however all the threads I saw on this topic did not help me hence I'm posting.

I am attempting to host a WCF HTTP service on IIS 5.1. It is extremely basic. I created a virtual directory in IE called `wcftest`, which points to the actual folder containing the contents of the service. Here is the structure:

```
Web.config
ConsoleWCF.svc
[App_Code] \ Program.cs
```

Here is the code for `ConsoleWCF.svc`

```
<%@ ServiceHost Debug="true" Service="ConsoleWCF.WCFImplementer" Language="C#" %>
```

The Web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleWCF.WCFImplementer" 
               behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint 
            address="" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="ConsoleWCF.WCFInterface" />
        <endpoint 
            address="mex" 
            binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And finally the `Program.cs` is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace ConsoleWCF
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface WCFInterface
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetData();
    }

    public class WCFImplementer : WCFInterface
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "Tested Console WCF";
        }
    }
}
```

I can access this in IE by browsing to http://localhost/wcftest/ConsoleWCF.svc.

However I do not understand how to access the `GetData` method I have. When I did this using a stand-alone host, I had no issues accessing it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `basicHttpBinding` endpoint is a **SOAP** endpoint - and you cannot just "browse" to a SOAP endpoint and have it do something. You need a SOAP client - like the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to talk SOAP to your service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for WCF to understand the `[WebGet]` attribute, the endpoint needs to have a certain configuration, namely use the `webHttpBinding` (not `basicHttpBinding` as you do) and to have a `WebHttpBehavior` added to it. If you change the `web.config` to something like the one below, you should be able to browse to `http://localhost/wcftest/ConsoleWCF.svc/GetData`.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="REST">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="ConsoleWCF.WCFImplementer">
      <endpoint address=""
                behaviorConfiguration="REST"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="ConsoleWCF.WCFInterface" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```